# If custom field exists or not

Tags: 2007, list, column

I got one custom boolean column/field which I want to check if it exists or not before checking its value, currently I am using this code but it ain't working like it should,

```
    using (SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists["List Name"];

        foreach (SPListItem listItem in list.Items)
        {
            if (listItem.Properties["Boolean Property"] != null &&
                    bool.Parse(listItem.Properties["Boolean Property"].ToString()) == false)
            {
                //continue
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

I am using .Net framework 3.5 so can't use fieldexsist property.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

listItem.Properties will show metadata properties, not fields. Not sure which one you want.

I use the following to check if a field exists:

```
list.Fields.ContainsField("fieldname")
```

Likewise, for metadata properties you can use:

```
listItem.Properties.ContainsKey("property name")
```